# How to understand which partition replica kafka broker is down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, yahoo-kafka-manager

There's topic with 22 replicas, 50 partitions and 22 running Kafka brokers.

Topic manual assignment screen in Kafka Manager shows that there's **Broker Down** in all topic partitions as seen in the image.

How to determine Kafka broker that's down using cli or Kafka Manager?

Currently, i look which broker id is missing in Partition replicas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This information on brokers is also maintained in Zookeeper. So, you could go onto one of the zookeeper nodes and use the cli to extract this and here's a command sequence you could use:

1. On the command line, just issue the command `zookeeper-client` and this should invoke the zookeeper command prompt
2. On the new prompt, issue the command - `ls /brokers/ids` and this should return the ids of all the active brokers